# git push origin branch名 でbranch名を補完したい

Tags: git

新しくbranchを切ると、branch名はhistoryにないので補完されません。
現在のブランチを補完するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

使用しているシェルはZshです

Comment: git-completion等での補完設定はされている前提でしょうか？

Comment: http://qiita.com/mabots/items/76d48aa33720287253bf `git push origin HEAD` で済む話でした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git-completion等の設定はこのあたりが参考になるのではないでしょうか。
http://wada811.blogspot.com/2013/06/zsh-git-completion.html
http://please-sleep.cou929.nu/git-completion-and-prompt.html

もしpushする作業を楽にしたいという目的であれば

```
git config --global push.defaul current
```

と設定すると

```
git push origin
```

で現在のbranchにpushできるので、こちらも試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

参考
http://www.yunabe.jp/docs/relearning_git_push_default.html
http://qiita.com/dehali22/items/09cc89ed87f022668d80